# How can i disable show effect in jquery tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have used jquery tabs with ASP.NET HiddenField for save selected tab.

If i try this source code then i have automatic effect - fadeIn in show tab.

How can i remove this effect in showing tab?

I have following javascript code:

```
$(function () {
   $("#tabs").tabs({
       show: function() {
          var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
          $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
          },
       selected: <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
   });
 });

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTab" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ show: { effect: "none"} });
```

You can get more option from the [Jquery UI documention.](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show)

Comment: Where can I put my function? function() {
          var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
          $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
          }

Comment: @Jenan what do you want using hidden field value ? as your question says you don't want to use default fadIn effect of Jquery tab, So it can be done simply using above code. If you want something else then plx specify so that i can understand.

Comment: I need to remove fadeIn effect and save selected value to hiddenfield. How can you change my source code?

Comment: Can i set effect parameter and set the callback function for save the value in hiddenfield?